# Programming for Windows Phone 8.0 without a phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm learning C# and I would like to start programming for Windows Phone, but I don't have an actual Windows Phone device. Is it possible to begin without a device? Is the emulator good enough to check functionality or is a device required?

Also, are there any differences between Windows Phone 7 and 8?

Comment: The emulator will allow you to check most of the functionality, but the only way to really ensure your app works on that environment is to buy a device and actually run it. Of course, you can put that purchase off as long as possible, and get the cheapest device needed to verify your functionality. I'm thinking an old model that's scratched up and available used on eBay. Once you release the app and make a little cash (good luck!) you can then use the profit to buy additional testing devices for the most popular models.

Answer (score 1):

The emulators that come with Visual Studio (and, I assume, Express, but I've never used that) are very good. Again, I've never used Express, but I'm pretty positive that if you're in an environment that supports development for such devices, you should already have them installed.

As for your real question, which I suppose I haven't answered, it's really up to you whether it's "worth it." You can do it, and you can write acceptable apps using only the emulators. But I wouldn't publish something to the store without testing it on a real device (or several). You can pick one up for pretty cheap these days, though. If I were you, I would get started. It doesn't hurt to have the experience, and like I said you can write a good app using only the emulator. It'll definitely put you ahead of the curve when you *do* get a physical device.

And yes, there are many differences between Windows Phone 7 and WP8. But I wouldn't bother learning anything about 7 since it isn't really used by anyone any more.

Comment: @W92 ,I believe the emulators that come with the express edition are the same as all other versions of VS, so I'd agree with this. If you do not the emulators installed, you may wish to look into Hyper-V and whether your computer supports it as it is required to run the emulators

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need [Channel9 windows phone](http://channel9.msdn.com/WindowsPhone) or [Microsoft Virtual Academy Mobile Development](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-topics/mobile-development)

1) - As you mentioned you have just started so don't worry about anything just start with VisualStudio Built in Emulators. Emulators are available for each and every resolution you may not have many phones. `Phone is not needed at all for initial phase of exploring.`

2) - For getting knowledge for `difference between Windows phone 7 and Windows phone 8` Actually you forgot to mention about `Windows phone 8.1` So it would be much better if you just explore about Windows phone development e.g Tools needed, New updates etc. You can search the above links i have provided i think those links are the best ones.

3) - Getting knowledge is always worth.

Hope it help you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

What most people aren't aware of, is that Nokia provides free remote device access to a great number of Windows Phone devices, and yes real devices, not emulators! If you want to see the design & functionality of your app, analyze the detailed log of installation, run and so on, give it a try: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access

Note: It only requires Nokia Developer membership, which is completely free as well.

Answer (score 1):

I learned Windows Phone app development without any device and then I got free device in MS campaign. You can start with Visual Studio Express Edition http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-express-windows-8. Emulators are good enough to begin with.

If you are going to develop app which uses device sensors, then you should test on real device before publishing the app.

If you are going to use any ARM specific 3rd part library, then you can't develop with Simulators.

WP 7 has gone and you can't target that version in VS 2013 Express.

Keep looking around for Microsoft campaign where you can get free device. You can try http://www.dvlup.com to get free device.

Answer (score 0):

go through this [Microsoft windows phone getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529(v=vs.105).aspx)